# .NET developer CV issue

Tags: software-industry, career-development, software-development

We know things like ADO.NET and Winforms are part of .NET.

Now, how do you classify these technologies when it comes to CV :

1) e.g. do you just write knowledge of .NET and let them figure out what you know?

or

2) list these particularly e.g. Winforms, ADO.NET, .NET?
But problem here is you are repeating yourself. The latter item .NET contains the first two. So how do you go about this?

Maybe?
Winforms, ADO.NET, .NET BCL?

Comment: Do they specify those technologies on their job description? Then make sure to mention them. If they only ask for .NET then you can probably leave it at that.

Comment: Good point. I also think like that

Comment: Keep in mind codenoir's advice though. He makes a very good point. Recruiters and HR are typically very ignorant. They mostly play buzzword bingo with our resumes.

Comment: @AndreiROM Yeah I see just this makes sense that if in job requirement only .NET is stated - you can include only .NET, otherwise list them

Comment: They may be "part of .NET" but you could have years of experience with .NET and yet never have worked with them.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
".NET and related technologies such as ___, ___, ___, ___"
```

There are hordes of related technologies, and I'm sure a recruiter or hiring manager is probably going to be specific in his/her interest.  It might seem a little tedious, but you'll do more good by including them.

The recruiters and HR people DON'T CARE about what seems repetitive. They are not developers. They scan resumes and look for keywords, and filter accordingly. Missing keywords means no interviews. That's just the way it is.   Yes, it's inefficient; I've actually put "Transact-SQL" and "T-SQL" on my resume because they are clueless to the fact that they're the same thing. Don't be a snob, because it's going to keep many doors closed for you.

(I'm also a .NET developer.)

Comment: related technologies isn't really correct because stuff I listed like ADO winforms are actually *part* of .NET

Comment: You're missing the point.  The recruiters DON'T CARE.  They are not developers.  They scan resumes and look for keywords.  Missing keywords means no interviews.  That's just the way it is.  It's so stupid, I've actually put "Transact-SQL" and "T-SQL" on my resume because they are clueless to the fact that they're the same thing.  Don't be a snob, because it's going to keep many doors closed for you.

Comment: That should be part of your answer.  It is important to explain why your answer is correct.  Explaining that Recruiters and HR types are just looking to check off requirements would help improve this answer greatly.

Comment: Good point, Chad.

Comment: But 5 page resumes also mean no interviews either...

Comment: @AmyBlankenship that's true.  But a keyword list doesn't add much bulk.

Comment: It can, especially if recruiters want to see what jobs you did test driven development, version control, worked with millions of records, blah blah blah. So if you are trying to highlight that you didn't just pick up skills, X, Y, and Z 2 weeks ago from Pluralsight it can add quite a but of bulk.

Comment: It is always better to target your resume to a real person. Recruiters that scan for keywords typically provide worthless leads. There's nothing wrong with having a version of the resume with a keyword "bingo section" to use for such long shots, but when you know it is going to a hiring manager use the advice in Thomas Owens answer.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to list skills on your resume. My advice: don't.

Instead of listing skills, talk about the things that you did in each position. If you had a job where you did .NET development and used Winforms or ADO.NET, put that in the description of the job. If the company is looking for specific skills and mention them in the job posting, you can use a cover letter to introduce times when you've worked with a particular set of skills, or related skills where you can transfer your knowledge and experiences.

If you maintain a profile on something like Stack Overflow Careers or LinkedIn, you can use the appropriate sections there for keywords to help make yourself discoverable to people searching. However, even on these sites, you should write about the technologies that you use in the context of jobs you've held and projects you've worked on as well.

Comment: i have listed what i did on each job too

Comment: @user400500 Then don't bother enumerating the technology that you know. It's one thing to have keywords on a website such as Stack Overflow Careers or LinkedIn, where people may be searching for you. Once you export to a PDF or print a paper copy, that kind of information just takes up space. Instead, focus on writing good descriptions of your roles, responsibilities, and achievements and using your cover letter to address specifics about why you are a good fit for a particular position.

Comment: I have listed what kind of programming tasks I did on my job roles using which tech; I will list the tech too, they won't hurt. Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @user400500 Like I said, it should never just be a list of the tools and technologies. It should be part of the story of the job. You should tie the tools into things that you did and things that you achieved.

Comment: I disagree with the advice to remove the list of skills.  As noted in codenoir's answer, many people reviewing your resume want to quickly scan it to see if you meet basic job requirements.  Yes, the more detailed information is helpful, but this should be in addition to the list, not a substitute for it.

Comment: @dan1111 I have reviewed resumes, generally for intern and entry level positions. I dislike a list of skills because I don't know how you learned it. Did you use it in one class? Did you make a project? Or did you use it for 6 months and make a few things? Of course, I take the 10 minutes to read the resume. If it's well-formatted, it shouldn't take me longer to read 4 pages. The only time that a list of skills is good is, like teego1967 says in a comment, when you're trying to get through recruiters who keyword-scan and don't put human thought into the skills and experiences of a candidate.

Comment: I agree with all you say about the limitations of the list of skills...but there is no harm in having both the list and more detailed information.  The skill list takes little space.  And the reality is plenty of people keyword scan (not just recruiters, also HR departments), so there may be a real cost of omitting it.  (I review resumes, and generally go into more detail like you, but I still like the skill list to get a quick sense of what technologies someone has been exposed to).

Comment: @dan1111 A list does not take "little space" in all cases. I just typed what I would put as my skills (both technologies and concepts) in a full-width Word document at 10 point Times New Roman font separating and It was about 8 lines. If I applied formatting to separate them into concepts, languages, frameworks, or any other set of categories, it would probably be approaching 12-15 lines of text. That's too long. It's fine if you disagree, but the advice I always give when I review resumes is to remove objectives and skills lists as they don't help me decide between candidates.